# Power BI parameter for image

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I wanted to know if there's a way to have a parameter that holds an image.

**The problem:** I have 10 PBIX, each one containing over 20 screens. every report has the clients logo. it is an image let's say the client changed his logo, that means I'll need to change the logo 200 times!! (10 PBIX X 20 screens).

**Wanted solution:** is there a way to hold a parameter that will contain the logo, therefore changing the logo only 10 times (for each PBIX) that will be a HUGE improvement for my time and productivity. sorry for not including pictures this is to keep my client anonymous

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the logo exists? In database? Or in folder location?

Comment: its in a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve your requirement as stated below-

**Step-1** create a custom function in Power Query as stated below. The function is taken from [Here](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2018/01/storing-images-powerbi-analysis-services-data-models/) and you can check this blog for more details if you are interested.

```
let 
    BinaryToImage = (BinaryContent as binary) as text =>
let 
    Base64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " & Binary.ToText(BinaryContent, BinaryEncoding.Base64)
in
    Base64
in
    BinaryToImage
```

Here below is the image for the custom function-

[image]

**Step-2** create report wise folder in your local directory and keep your image there. I am considering one folder here, but you can do your own once you get the workaround.

**Step-3** Create a data connection for **Folder** as shown below and point to the folder you kept your logo/image-

[image]

And now you will have a table as below with one row as there are one image only. I named the table as **PBI_Images**.

[image]

Here basically **Content** column holding the Binary data for the image and we have to convert it to Base64 using the Function we created earlier.

**Step-4** Now lets Invoke the function in our table. Select the table and do what shown in the below image-

[image]

Now you have a new column with data like below-

[image]

**Step-5** Get back to report by clicking "Close & Apply" button.

**Step-6** Download the following App from AppStore-

[image]

**Step-7** Just add the new downloaded visual to your report and put the newly created column to the "Image URL" field as below-

[image]

**Step-8** Now add the Image visual to all your report pages and tag the Image URL as stated in step-7.

You are all done now. Just Change the Image in your source file keeping the same name and after that refresh your table (PBI_Images my case) and you will see Image changes everywhere in the report.

**Finally,** if everything works expected, you can first try will all logos from one single folder. If do not work, go for folder per customer as mentioned earlier.

Comment: the limit of Base64 is an image size of 32kb, so when I have implemented something similar the stored formats should be that size or less